# Arrangement of Amino Acids in the Protein alphabet

Tags: biochemistry, proteins, amino-acids

I am a software engineer with little knowledge of molecular biology. However I am trying to understand some bioinformatics computer code where the protein alphabet appears to be represented as the following string, with each of the twenty amino acid constituents of protein:

```
ACDEFGHIKLMNPQRSTVWY
```

The code appears to define a second string in which the first is reordered as:

```
DEKRHNQSTPGAVILMCFYW
```

I am not sure of the biological significance of this. Does this reordering represent some specific interaction between these molecules?

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. Have you looked at a [table of amino acid properties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amino_acid#Table_of_standard_amino_acid_abbreviations_and_properties)? There are many ways of grouping amino acids, so if it isn't documented why that order is being used I doubt anyone can give you a definitive answer beyond the trivial 'ordered by physicochemical properties'.

Comment: @tyersome But the mapping given by the OP doesn't appear to be based on physicochemical properties at all?

Comment: @user338907 — What makes you say that? DE = "acidic", KRH = "basic" etc. (see also acvill's answer), you seem confused there is no mention by the OP of this being a mapping ...

Comment: What is the context? HPLC? Mass spectrometry? 2D gels? Sucrose gradients? Protein folding? What kind of analysis?

Comment: OP is probably referring to [this](https://github.com/ArnaudFickinger/DeepSequence-PyTorch/blob/bed7744c6573c16a46f799a540e175f90fcecf3d/utils.py#L126-L128).

Comment: That is exactly right @voile

I have been looking at the DeepSequence paper and its implementation where you have related protein sequence aligned with each other and one is trying to develop a statistical model over their distribution.

Comment: I rephrased the question to align it to the accepted answer and to avoid a biologically misleading title. Although not a Python devotee, looking at the code in the link given by @Voile it would appear that I am incorrect in my comment that these are not strings. The answer would seem to be that the second string has been reordered on the basis (better a particular assignment) of amino acid properties. Why strings are being used in this way is not evident to any molecular biologist, or anyone else without analysing the code.

Comment: @Luce Thank you for your contribution. As the algorithm for the paper you refer to is neither standard or self-evident, I for one would find very useful if you could provide an answer explaining it.

Comment: @David So I analyzed the code a bit and this reordering thing seems to be a red herring. Must be hangover of some old code as it does not seem to be used anywhere...

Comment: @Luca — Strange. I'll have a look at it myself perhaps. I am having to work on someone else's Django code at the moment, so I might as well try to suss out the Python. If it beats me I have friends I can lean on. This whole thing would have probably been better on SE Bioinformatics, although I don't go there much.

Comment: Ah right...yes, did not know about that SE!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As suggested by tyersome's comment, the amino acids are grouped by their physiochemical properties. Let's add some commas:

```
DE,KRH,NQ,ST,PGAVIL,MC,FYW
```

- aspartic acid (`D`) and glutamic acid (`E`) are acidic
- lysine (`K`), arginine (`R`), and histidine (`H`) are basic
- asparagine (`N`) and glutamine (`Q`) are amidic
- serine (`S`) and threonine (`T`) are hydroxylic
- proline (`P`), glycine (`G`), alanine (`A`), valine (`V`), isoleucine (`I`), and leucine (`L`) are aliphatic
- methionine (`M`) and cysteine (`C`) are sulfur-containing
- phenylalanine (`F`), tyrosine (`Y`), and tryptophan (`W`) are aromatic

My source is [this graphic.](https://web.archive.org/web/20210121150248/https://i0.wp.com/www.compoundchem.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/20-Common-Amino-Acids-v3.png?ssl=1)

Comment: Thank you! Lots to take in!

Comment: I am the person who came up with that reordering and I can confirm that acvill is correct. Specifically, the hope was that in heat maps relating the sequence to other properties like colours would show up in clusters. It actually does not work that great but it's the best you can do arranging them in one dimension.

Comment: I have deleted my previous comment about strings as it transpires, to my surprise, that the computer code contains the two 20 amino acid sequences as strings. So your answer might be modified to say that "the second string contains the 20 amino acids arranged so that those of similar physiochemical properties are grouped together". The reason for constructing such strings can only be discerned from an understanding of the computer algorithm.

Comment: @David I will contact the authors and update the thread.